# a service in ecs fails to find another service within the same network

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I have a very simple `docker-compose` for `locust` (python package for load testing). It starts a 'master' service and a 'slave' service. Everything works perfectly locally but when I deploy it to AWS ECS a 'slave' can't find a master.

```
services:
  my-master:
    image: chapkovski/locust
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      LOCUST_MODE: master

  my-slave:
    image: chapkovski/locust
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      LOCUST_MODE: slave
      LOCUST_MASTER_HOST: my-master
```

So apparently I need to refer from `my-slave` service not to `my-master` when I am on ECS. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything works perfectly locally but when I deploy it to AWS ECS
>   a 'slave' can't find a master.

I assume that slave needs to access master both must be in the same task definition to access like this or you can explore [service discovery](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecs-service-discovery/)?

```
  "links": [
      "master"
    ]
```

**links**

```
Type: string array

Required: no
```

> The link parameter allows containers to communicate with each other
>   without the need for port mappings. Only supported if the network mode
>   of a task definition is set to bridge. The name:internalName construct
>   is analogous to name:alias in Docker links.

**Note**

This parameter is not supported for Windows containers or tasks using the awsvpc network mode.

**Important**

> Containers that are collocated on a single container instance may be
>   able to communicate with each other without requiring links or host
>   port mappings. Network isolation is achieved on the container instance
>   using security groups and VPC settings.

```
"links": ["name:internalName", ...]
```

[container_definition_network](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_network)